# Where to store complete first names, middle names, and last names in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory

I have the following name in my country:

Juan Jose Perez Gomez

where

(1) first name is "Juan Jose",

(2) middle name (Father's surname) is "Perez" and

(3) second name (Mother's surname) is "Gomez"

Which Active Directory *property names* do you recommend to use for storing (1), (2), and (3) separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `givenName` for First name,  `initials` to store middle name and `sn` for last name?

**Edit:** Looks like the `initials` column will accept only 6 characters. There is a `Display name` column. Can't you use this for displaying the whole name and store First and/or middle name in `givenName` and `sn` for last name.

The initial idea of storing middle name in initial was from a blog which had a sample code. The author had used `initials` for middle name. After reading your comment I checked the active directory and found the limitation in the length.

Comment: Thanks Shoban, please let me ask you if the properties you kindly suggested to me aren't critical for Exchange, SharePoint or Domain Administration when I begin to populate or update them. Thanks!!

Comment: @Vizcaynot .. Added some more info. Please check.

Comment: Shoban, I took in account "givenName" for name, "sn" for Father's surname and, instead of initials y used one of the extensionAttributes offered by Active Directory for storing mother's surname. Thanks for your guidelines. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Using the extensionAttributes for storing data is not ideal especially if it is quite specific, such as part of the name. Also extensionAttributeX attributes only exist (unless you create them yourself), in an AD environment with MS Exchange installed.

The best way would be to create your own attribute in the AD schema.

I did a quick google search and found [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169630) article which looks good.

Comment: Custom attributes in Active Directory are irreversible. Once created it can not be deleted or modified. For that reason I always use extensionAttributes

Answer (score -1):

I would go for using attribute editor option in AD to set names as `firstName`, fathers name as `middleName` and mothers name as `lastName`.