# Find AD user information with DisplayName

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a list of displaynames and I need to get their AD informations.

```
Get-Content "C:\displaynames.txt" |
foreach {
    $givenname,$surname = $_ -split ' '
                 if (Get-ADUser -Filter "surname -eq '$surname' -and givenname -eq '$givenname'"){
                     Get-ADUser -Filter { displayName -match $_} -Properties EmailAddress, Manager | Select Givenname, Surname, SamAccountName, EmailAddress, Manager}
                  else {Get-ADUser -Filter { displayName -like "AD Test"} -Properties EmailAddress, Manager | Select Givenname, Surname, SamAccountName, EmailAddress, Manager}  
     } | Export-Csv -Path C:\result.csv
```

This works fine, but only if users have no middle names ex. John Moore
If the user has a middle name, it doesn't pick it up.
How can I change the script so it picks up users with middle names ex. John Roger Moore?

Comment: It depends on how you have config username informations like name, surname etc...(eg. if you have set John Roger as name and then Moore as surname, you will find John Roger as name as well.)

Comment: Why not just filter on `displayName` directly: `Get-ADUser -Filter "displayName -eq '$_'"`?

Comment: I've found this post which could help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288534/where-to-store-complete-first-names-middle-name-and-last-name-in-active-directo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288534/where-to-store-complete-first-names-middle-name-and-last-name-in-active-directo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen)  already commented, you can use the `-Filter` on property DisplayName directly.
The Filter should be a **string**, not a scriptblock.

Using `-Filter` also has the advantage that you can suppress exceptions being thrown, so I would build in a step to confirm that we indeed did find a user with that displayname:

```
Get-Content "C:\displaynames.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUSer -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$_'" -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, Manager -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        # output the wanted properties as **object**
        $user | Select-Object Givenname, Surname, SamAccountName, EmailAddress, Manager
    }
    else {
        # nobody in this domain with a displayname like that..
        Write-Warning "User '$_' could not be found.."
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\result.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>Note that the `Manager` property is in the form of the managers **DistinguishedName**. If you want to get other properties for the manager, like his/her name, you will have to use `Get-ADUser -Identity $user.Manager` to get the wanted property there too</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The basic question here is how to account for middle names.

PowerShell 5 has some AI-powered cmdlets.

Here, I will quote an example from the documentation.

> ### Example 2: Simplify format of a string
>
> ```
> $composers = @("Johann Sebastian Bach", "Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart", "Frederic Francois Chopin", "Johannes Brahms")
> $composers | Convert-String -Example "first middle last=last, first"
>
> Bach, Johann
> Mozart, Wolfgang
> Chopin, Frederic
> Brahms, Johannes
> ```
>
> The first command creates an array that contains first, middle and last names. Note that the last entry has no middle name.
>
> The second command formats the names according to the example. It puts the last name first in the output, followed by the first name. All middle names removed; entry without middle name is handled correctly.

- [Convert-String (Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility) - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convert-string?view=powershell-5.1#example-2--simplify-format-of-a-string)